# React: usenav hooks works for a sec and then page reloads back to login page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router

`I have been trying to create a simple login page which uses Login API. I have used usenav hook but when I login successfully I can see the usenav work for just a sec and the page reloads back to the login page. Please help me, I am new to react and have been trying to figure it out for over a month now.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';


function Login() {
    const password = useRef("");
    const username = useRef("");
    const validate = useRef("");
    const [usernName, setuserName] = useState([]);
    const [passWord, setpassWord] = useState([]);
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState([{ value: 'false' }]);
    const nav = useNavigate();
    
    const LoginValidate = async (un, pw, e) => {

        let message = "";
        var mheaders = new Headers();
        mheaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        var raw = JSON.stringify({

            "username": un,
            "password": pw
        });

        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: mheaders,
            body: raw,
            redirect: 'follow'
        };
        console.log("Hi");

        var res = fetch("http://localhost:8080/v1/user/verifyuser", requestOptions).then(response => response.text()).then(result => {
            if (result === "successful") {
                setSuccess(true);
                console.log("Hiyaaaaa");


            }
            else setSuccess(false);
        });
    }

    return (
        (success ?
            nav('/gettodolist/4') : <div className="loginmaindiv">
                <div >
                    <form onSubmit={() => LoginValidate(usernName, passWord)}>
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input ref={username} type="text" value={usernName} onChange={(e) => setuserName(e.target.value)}></input>
                        <br />
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input ref={password} type="password" value={passWord} onChange={(e) => setpassWord(e.target.value)}></input>
                        <br />
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                        <div ref={validate}></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div>

                </div>
            </div>

        )

    )

}

export default Login;
```

When I Login with correct credentials I should see the list of my ToDo items which is fetched using API call.

Issue:
I can see the ToDo items page only for a sec and the page reloads back to login page.`

Comment: You should use `<Redirect />` rather than putting nav `nav()` in the JSX. Even better, skip the success state and navigate using `nav()` when the fetch resolves

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using the success state to conditionally render the login page, but the way you initialized it is what's probably causing your challenge.

Try initializing it like this:

```
const [success, setSuccess] =useSate(false)
```

Additionally, add `e.preventDefault()` to the first line in the "Login Validate" function, preventing the application from rerendering when you submit the form.